# Column line overshooting the horizontal line in table

Tags: tables, multirow

```
\begin{tabular}{|m{3.5cm}|m{5.5cm}|m{4.5cm}|}
\hline
\emph{Category of Benefits} & \emph{General Benefit} & \emph{Operational Advantages} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\pbox{3.5cm}{Robust operational performance}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\pbox{5.5cm}{One sensor can contribute information while other are unavailable, denied(jammed), or lack coverage of a target or event}} & -Allows continued operation despite jamming \\
&  & -Graceful degradation \\
&  & -Increased probability of detection \\ \hline

\multirow{2}{*}{\pbox{3.5cm}{Extended spatial coverage}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\pbox{5.5cm}{One sensor can look where another cannot}} & -Increased survivability \\
&  & -Probability of detection increased  \\
\hline
\label{tab1.1}
\end{tabular}
```

For the LateX code mentioned above the table which comes looks like this
![enter image description here][1]

In the resulting table, column 1 vertical line overshoots the last horizontal line.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a spurious final row because of the `\label{tab1.1}` which is inside the table. It should be outside the `tabular` just after (or inside) the `\caption` command for the surrounding `table`.