# How to erase the little tip at the end of my table?

Tags: tables, formatting

I generated some tables through the TablesGenerator.com and they all came out with the little tip and the end (look at the last row).

How do I get rid of that? Here's the code (sorry for the crappy formatting, first post ever):

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Especificações do projeto do conversor \emph{boost} baaseado na 3SSC.}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Parâmetro}}                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Valor}}           \\ \hline
Tensão de entrada                                                                                  & $V_{i}$ = 48 V                                 \\ \hline
Potência de saída                                                                                  & $V_{o}$ = 400 V                                \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Número de enrolamentos secundários \\ no autotransformador\end{tabular} & $P_{o}$ = 1 kW                                 \\ \hline
Razão cíclica nominal                                                                              & $D$=0.76                                        \\ \hline
Ondulação da tensão de saída                                                                       & $\Delta V_{o}$ = 5\% $V_{o}$                  \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ondulação da tensão nos capacittores \\ $C_{2}$ e $C_{3}$\end{tabular}  & $\Delta V_{C1}$ = 5\% $V_{C1}$                \\ \hline
Ondulação de corrente no indutor                                                                 & $\Delta L$ = 5\% $I_{i}$                      \\ \hline
Frequência de comutação                                                                            & $f_{s}$ = 25 kHz                               \\ \hline
Indutância L                                                                              & $L$ = 479,23 $\mu$F             \\ \hline
Capacitor $C_{1}$                                                                                  & $C_{1}$ = 2,6 $\mu$F            \\ \hline
Capacitores $C_{2}$ e $C_{3}$                                                                      & $C_{2}$ = $C_{3}$ = 15,2 $\mu$F \\ \hline
\label{Tab:valores_proj}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Do you really need all rows to demonstrate your problem? // Nobody can use your code, as it will never compile when copied ... // Kindly improve your posted code; about 10-20 lines of code should be all you need to show your problem ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Move `\label{…}` either before the first `\begin{tabular}` (behind `\caption{…}`) or behind the last `\end{tabular}`. Currently it starts a new table row.

Comment: -cabohah Thanks! That did it! Really appreciate man!

Comment: BTW: The generated code is not the best. I recommend to learn how to make such easy tables manually and also remove all vertical and most of the horizontal lines. See, e.g., the manual of package [`booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for information about making better tables.

Answer (score 2):

How to avoid creating an overshoot of the vertical rules has already been dealt with in [Getting extra cell at bottom of table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/292563/5001) and, earlier still, in [Column line overshooting the horizontal line in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111720/5001).

There are additional infelicities in your table that are worth fixing. Chief among the possible improvements are (a) allowing automatic line breaking in the first column, (b) employing automatic math mode in the second column, (c) typesetting quantities and their associated scientific units consistently and professionally, and (d) giving the table a more open and inviting "look" by omitting all vertical rules and using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules. Take a look at the following screenshot for an implementation of these ideas.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % or 'brazil'?
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1}X}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{siunitx} % for '\qty' and '\num' macros
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}} % use commas as decimal markers

\begin{document}

\begin{table} 
\centering
\caption{Especificações do projeto do conversor \emph{boost} baaseado na 3SSC.} 
\label{Tab:valores_proj}

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{@{} L >{$}l<{$} @{}} % automatic math mode for 2nd column
\toprule 
Parâmetro & \mbox{Valor} \\ 
\midrule 
Tensão de entrada                  & V_{i} = \qty{48}{\volt} \\  
Potência de saída                  & V_{0} = \qty{400}{\volt} \\  
Número de enrolamentos secundários 
no autotransformador               & P_{0} = \qty{1}{\kilo\watt} \\  
Razão cíclica nominal              & D = \num{0.76} \\  
Ondulação da tensão de saída       & \Delta V_{0} = 5\%\,V_{0} \\  
Ondulação da tensão nos 
capacittores $C_{2}$ e $C_{3}$     & \Delta V_{C1} = 5\% \,V_{C1} \\  
Ondulação de corrente no indutor   & \Delta L = 5\%\,I_{i} \\  
Frequência de comutação            & f_{s} = \qty{25}{\kilo\hertz} \\  
Indutância $L$                     & L = \qty{479,23}{\micro\farad} \\  
Capacitor $C_{1}$                  & C_{1} = \qty{2,6}{\micro\farad} \\  
Capacitores $C_{2}$ e $C_{3}$      & C_{2} = C_{3} = \qty{15,2}{\micro\farad} \\ 
\bottomrule  
\end{tabularx} 

\end{table}

\end{document}
```